# How to perform multiple nightmare function without it hanging up

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to scrape a webpage with nightmareJS and got stuck.
In my program i pass to the function an array on links which i need to the same data from all of them 
The list can be very long (over 60) and if i try to do a

```
async.each(Links, function (url, callback) {
    var nightmare = Nightmare(size);
    ...
}
```

Only the first couple few instances actually return a value , others just hang up and wont load (blank page).When i try to do only three it work perfectly. 
How can i fix it? How can i redistribute the work , for example three in parallel and only when all done it will do the next set? One more thought maybe use the same instance and repeat the steps for all the links?

Comment: eachSeries may help, so it does one page at a time.

Comment: Looks promising ,  will try at home

Comment: You can use async.queue and set the number of parallel tasks you want to perform at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

- using `eachSeries` which waits until one operation is done before launching the other one.
- Or in `async.each`pass another argument which limits how many operation are running in the same time.